# Alterar a ordem de um resultado no WHILE do PHP vindo do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade, em uma tabela estão armazenadas registros de categorias de produto, fiz a conexão mysqli, o SELECT e o WHILE, e está tudo bem até aí, porém o que estou com dificuldade é deixar um registro do WHILE por último, no caso seria o registro de categoria chamado "OUTROS", pois o SELECT está com ORDER BY `cat_nome` ASC; e abaixo de "OUTROS" existem outras categorias com nomes que começam com "P", "Q", "R", "S" (...).

Resumindo o SELECT, está assim:

```
<?php
$sql_cat_cad = "SELECT 
                   `cat_id`,
                   `cat_nome`
                FROM 
                    `categoria` 
                WHERE 
                    `cat_id_pai` IS NULL
                ORDER BY 
                    `cat_nome`
                        ASC
                ";

$query_cat_cad = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql_cat_cad );
$conta_cat_cad = mysqli_num_rows( $query_cat_cad );
if( $conta_cat_cad > 0 ) {
    echo "<select name='categorias' id='categorias'>\n";
    echo "<option value=''>Selecione a categoria</option>\n";
    while( $cat = mysqli_fetch_array( $query_cat_cad ) ) {
        echo "<option value='" . $cat['cat_id'] . "'>" . stripslashes( $cat['cat_nome'] ) . "</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
}
?>
```

**Resultando resumidamente o WHILE:**

> Adaptadores
>
> Apoios para Antebraço
>
> Caixas de Som e Subwoofer
>
> Microfones
>
> Mouse Pads
>
> **Outros**
>
> Scanners
>
> Suportes de CPU
>
> USB Padlocks

**Gostaria de alterar o código para que ficasse assim:**

> Adaptadores
>
> Apoios para Antebraço
>
> Caixas de Som e Subwoofer
>
> Microfones
>
> Mouse Pads
>
> Scanners
>
> Suportes de CPU
>
> USB Padlocks
>
> **Outros**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve obter o `cat_id` relativo ao `cat_nome` "Outros". Dessa forma você pode fazer uma ordenação com teste de caso:

```
SELECT cat_id, cat_nome FROM categoria WHERE cat_id_pai IS NULL
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `cat_id`=<ID_QUE_ENCONTROU> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, cat_nome ASC
```

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

## EDIT

## Ordenando dinamicamente pelo termo:

```
SELECT `cat_id`, `cat_nome` FROM `categoria` WHERE `cat_id_pai` IS NULL
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `cat_nome`="Outros" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, `cat_nome` ASC
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, uma dúvida, se excluir o registro e cadastrar com um novo auto incremento, ,tem de alterar o SELECT novamente?

Comment: @EliseuB. sim, a menos que faça uma busca pela palavra para obter esse ID dinamicamente antes de chamar essa query. Se aceitar uma sugestão, o termo "Outros" (no intuito de "Outras opções") não costuma ser utilizado dessa forma. Por exemplo, pode existir situações (no futuro) onde há tantas categorias que talvez queira resumir algumas com a opção genérica "Outros". Se não for o caso, aconselho fazer essa busca antes da chamada.

Comment: Com um subquery na mesma sentença deve resolver isso então pra receber o id do registro, certo? Vou levar em consideração sua sugestão, mas para futuras implementações, pois neste caso existe diversas categorias pai

Comment: veja minha edição @EliseuB. esse teste de caso pode servir para qualquer parâmetro que queira

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela colaboração, gratidão!

Comment: @Bacco creio que não, pois a ajuda do Kiko me incentivou a estudar sobre o CASE, WHEN e THEN, do qual eu não tinha conhecimento.

Comment: Complicação desnecessária, bastaria um `ORDER BY cat_nome = "Outros", cat_nome,....` - veja funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a865dd/1

Comment: @EliseuB. seria como você dizer que aprendeu a usar martelo pra por parafuso na parede, mas se pra você fez bem, tá ótimo. Pro resto dos leitores, preferi deixar a solução direta mesmo, ai cada um opta pela que achar melhor. Só sugiro nesses casos pesquisar melhor no site, pois é o segundo post seu que vejo em poucos minutos que é duplicata.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu ponto de vista, marquei como válida pois pra mim funcionou, poderia adicionar uma resposta explicando assim poderia eu colocar a sua como a melhor resposta,, gratidão.

Comment: No link acima já tem respostas com o exemplo que eu dei, só repeti nos comments para ajudar você e o próprio Kiko a simplificar no uso do dia a dia. Quanto a resposta, se foi a que resolveu, está correto em marcar como aceita. Note que não estou dizendo que o CASE não funciona (até pq o query planner dá uma simplificada internamente), só acho legal deixar claro que tem como fazer bem mais simples

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu fui tão focado no problema de ordenação de um elemento em específico que até esqueci da ordenação pelo termo. Mostrei o CASE porque serve para muito mais, principalmente se houver outros casos de ordenação embutidos. Calma, jovens.